# Bring code from view into a popup in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebox

I want to bring this code from my view html into a popup when a link is clicked
Is that possible in Ruby on Rails? I already have the pop up working but I'm wondering about the code to show just the comments:

```
<div class = "comments"><% if post.comments.exists? %>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/someavatarlink %) <!-- Retrieves Gravatar -->
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
            <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %></div>
```

Added Ajax call to _comment_form.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to "Link", comment, :remote => true %>
      Comments
    <% end %></div></div> 
    <div id ="modal" class = "comments"><% if post.comments.exists? %>
      <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
                <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
        <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
        <% end %>
    <% end %></div>
```

Added def show into comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     def new
    @post = post.new(params[:post])
    end

def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end

   def create
    @post = post.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.post = @post
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

Created show.erb.js and put it into 'comments' and 'shared' folders

```
$("#popup").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "comments") %>');
```

Then finally wrote my partial which is in comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<% if post.comments.exists? %>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>

    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
            <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

**1. Ajax call**

To retrieve the data you use an Ajax call.

```
<%= link_to "Link", comment, :remote => true %>
```

Rails will evaluate these requests and will look for a .js view first (it will use .html if it does not exist).

Make also sure that the controller accepts requests to .js like

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**2. write js view**

Add a `show.erb.js` view to your Comments . This is a JavaScript file with ERB evaluation.
In this template use your js popup code and tell it to fill a div with your html code like so:

```
$("#popup").html('<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>');
```

This will render the comment. The only thing we need then is a partial to render the html of the comment.

**3. write partial for html**

Write a partial for the view part you want to have in the popup. This can then be used in a normal html view or the js view. To make it work with the code above call it `_comment.html.erb`

To know more about partials you can check the guides here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: I'm looking over your answer, but have a quick question. I have put the above code in my original post into 'shared/comment' and the file name is _comment.html.erb.  Can I use the <%= link_to %> here to render the view in the popup?

Comment: FYI - making the popup is something I already have working (I'm using facebox). My issue is trying to figure out what the link_to code should be given the above code in my original post

Comment: The link needs to be a "remote" link. I updated the answer. I am just a bit confused what you would like to show. Is it 'user' or 'comment'?    Guess you will figure out how to modify the code.

Comment: ok, updated based on your input. let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: I went step by step but I'm getting this error in views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end. I posted up all of the steps that I took in the updated post. Could you take a look?

Comment: The error is probably just the result of you leaving off an "end"  in your code.